# Are convex fractals possible?

Tags: fractals, convex-geometry

Is it possible to have a fractal shape (and by that I mean a shape with non-integer Minkowski dimension) that is convex? I'm pretty sure it isn't, as every example of a fractal I can think of is concave; that might be a lack of knowledge or imagination on my part, and I have no idea how you would approach a rigorous proof. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key idea is that convex sets either have nonempty interior or are contained in a lower dimensional hyperplane (see for example here [Convex Set with Empty Interior Lies in an Affine Set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590133/convex-set-with-empty-interior-lies-in-an-affine-set)). This means we can reduce the dimension until our set has nonempty interior. However, if your sets contains an open set it cannot be a fractal (see for example here [Hausdorff dimension of an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133796/hausdorff-dimension-of-an-open-set)).